# Can vitamin B17 cure cancer?

Tags: cancer, vitamins

I have heard that a 'vitamin B17' can cure cancer, but that the medical industry never talks about it, since making it legal would cause them loss of billions. But I have never found a reliable report on whether B17 really works or not. There is a question on 'vitamin B17' deficiency as a cause of cancer (see [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/55517/is-cancer-a-nutritional-vitamin-b17-deficiency)), however, not on 'vitamin B17' as a possible medication for cancer. What are the proposed mechanisms? And is there evidence that 'vitamin B17' really works in curing cancer?

Comment: The short answer is "no", but if you find a notable referenced claim saying that, you could try your luck on [skeptics.se] for confirmation.

Comment: @Mesentery: Even though related and heading towards the same direction I would not see it as a duplicate. Supplementing a deficiency or using a substance as a treatment for a disease are fundamentally different, justifying both questions independently. I will edit my answer to address that more directly.

Comment: @AlexDeLarge - duplicates are marked as such because of question similarity, not answer differences. If you could edit the question and stress the difference between this and linked question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited to SE Skeptics http://skeptics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @AliceD: In the proposed edit, the question is rephrased and I added a query for possible mechanisms by which 'vitamin B17' could potentially cure cancer - which also makes it suitable for Biology.SE.

Comment: @David Just because a question is a "better" fit for another SE network site doesn't mean that it's off topic on this one. While SE Skeptics would be a good place to find sources which refute a particular claim, Biology SE is a perfectly fine spot to ask about the underlying biology of the topic.

Comment: @R.M.— No. But it is an excuse that can be employed to off-load stuff that is obviously undesirable but not covered by the criteria presented to one when one votes to close a question.

Comment: No such thing as B17: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_vitamins

Comment: @David I see no reason to close these sorts of questions if they can be answered with biology. This is my interpretation of the current meta as well. If you disagree, I would suggest raising the issue in meta.

Comment: @BryanKrause — I certainly did not and do not solicit a discussion here. I voted to close and had to explain why, which automatically generated a comment. This provoked other comments to which I replied. I suppose it could be raised on meta, but for various reasons I'd prefer to leave it a while.

Comment: I agree that, although this question would be well fit for posting on Skeptics.SE, this question is on-topic here.

Comment: Look here for an explanation why the "medical industry" wouldn't want any cancer cure to be kept secret, and wouldn't "loose billions" if such a cure existed and was made public: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22770/has-the-cure-to-cancer-been-hidden-by-pharmaceutical-companies

Comment: Obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/1217/

Comment: Of course a mere vitamin can cure cancer. That's why millions of scientists world wide are spending their lives looking for a cure. /s

Comment: There is no such thing as "vitamin B17". You can take TNT, call it "vitamin B52" and try to sell it to people but it doesn't make it a vitamin.

Comment: See also [Is laetrile an efficient drug against cancer?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/16159/2004) on [skeptics.se].

Comment: @Agent_L I see what you did there.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[Laetrile/Amygdalin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amygdalin) has been claimed to be a suitable treatment for 'cancer' (which is a summary term for an extremely heterogeneous class of diseases). Even though laetrile/amygdalin in these claims is often called a vitamin, it **in fact is not a [vitamin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitamin) as the molecule is not essential for the metabolism ([Greenberg (1980)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/1097-0142(19800215)45:4%3C799::AID-CNCR2820450432%3E3.0.CO;2-6/abstract))**.

The claimed effects of laetrile/amygdalin are not only based on supplementing the molecule to balance a putative deficiency (with the false assumption that it is in fact necessary), though. Both other putative mechanisms are **based on reactions that form HCN/cyanide**: the enzyme $\beta$-Glucosidase breaks down laetrile/amygdalin and this reaction releases HCN. The argument now is that tumour cells have higher levels of $\beta$-Glucosidase which leads to accumulation of cyanide in tumour cells - with the effect of killing the tumour cells selectively. This would be great... if healthy and tumour cells actually had different levels of the enzyme. Unfortunately, they **seem to have similarly low levels of $\beta$-Glucosidase** (Greenberg (1980)). Even more problematic, Greenberg (1980) also reports elevated levels of $\beta$-Glucosidase in the liver and small intestine ... and you would not really want to release cyanide there.

There is a second mechanism, though: The enzyme $\beta$-Glucuronidase is claimed to be at higher levels in cancer tissue than in healthy tissues (leading to the same desirable effect described above). But again, there **does not seem to be a difference in enzyme levels between healthy and cancer tissues** ([Dorr and Paxinos (1977)](http://annals.org/aim/article/692293/current-status-laetrile)), and even more: **$\beta$-Glucuronidase does not even break down the molecule as laetrile/amygdalin has a glucoside bond** - so there is not even any cyanide release in that case ([Holzbecher et al. (1984)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.3109/15563658408992565)).

Additionally, there is **no clinical evidence that laetrile/amygdalin is an appropriate treatment for any form of cancer**. This topic has been reviewed substantially (see [Milazzo et al. (2006)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00520-006-0168-9) for a review and this fairly recent [Cochrane review by Milazzo and Horneber (2015)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/14651858.CD005476.pub4/full)) and **none of the studies included and analysed indicate any positive effect of laetrile/amygdalin**. On the contrary, the *in vivo* cyanide formation after laetrile/amygdalin uptake **makes the treatment very dangerous as it can lead to cyanide poisoning** (and death, eventually) - especially after oral uptake due to higher $\beta$-Glucosidase concentrations in the digestive system. The authors of the Cochrane review therefore conclude that

> The claims that laetrile or amygdalin have beneficial effects for cancer patients are not currently supported by sound clinical data. There is a considerable risk of serious adverse effects from cyanide poisoning after laetrile or amygdalin, especially after oral ingestion. The risk–benefit balance of laetrile or amygdalin as a treatment for cancer is therefore unambiguously negative.

Comment: "deficiency as a cause of cancer" and "the molecule is not essential for the metabolism" seem contradictory. Maybe I'm being overly simplistic in my understanding. Nevertheless, how could one have a deficiency in something that is not necessary to begin with? It either is necessary therefore causes a problem when deficient, or not essential, therefore its deficiency would not be a cause of any problem, namely cancer.

Comment: @jlaverde: Yes, you are right. The 'deficiency as a cause of cancer' builds on the false assumption that the molecule is in fact essential for the metabolism - which it is not. I clarified.

Comment: @jlaverde The whole point is that it is quackery: it is *not* a vitamin. There can not be a deficiency because it *isn't needed at all*.